# Gitlab Ci Pipeline Rules not working as intended

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

So I have two protected environments `stage` and `prod` and I'm trying to achieve the following :

- Trigger child pipeline when a merge request is opened and the target branch is protected and `stage`
- Trigger child pipeline when MR is merged to a protected branch and the branch name is `stage`
- Don't trigger child pipeline on opened merge requests for a protected environment and the with the name `prod`
- Trigger pipeline when MR is merged to a protected environment and the environment name is `prod`

```
build:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID && ($CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "stage")
      when: always 
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID && ($CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "prod")
      when: never 
  trigger:
    include: 
      - local: myapp/.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
```

Unfortunately, these rules don't trigger the child pipeline for the job it's specified for when I opened a MR for the `stage` protected branch. I'd appreciate any help.